# How to create an authorization policy for Anonymous users

Tags: .net-core, authorization

With .NET Core 5 - As I understand it, each and every user (regardless of whether they are logged in) is assigned an Identity. So an anonymous user will be assigned, by default, `Identity.User.IsAuthenticated == false`.

I can't work out how to express this as a policy. Does anyone know how to create an authorization policy to represent these anonymous users?

```
public static void AddAuthorizationAndPolicies(this IServiceCollection services)
 {
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
        //Policy for logged in user - straightforward
                options.AddPolicy("IsLoggedIn",
                    policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
                
        //Policy for admin user - straightforward
                options.AddPolicy("IsAdminUser",
                    policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));

        //policy for Anonymous users - *** How to do this ***?
                options.AddPolicy("IsAnonymousUser",
                    policy => policy.AddRequirements()); //???
          
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay it seems that one way to do this is to create a custom authorization requirement class, and then create a policy that uses it.

To create the custom authorization class (in this case named "AllowAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement")...

```
 public class AllowAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: 
        AuthorizationHandler<AllowAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AllowAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
        {
            var user = context.User;
            var userIsAnonymous = user?.Identity == null || !user.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated);
            //success is user IS anonymous
            if (userIsAnonymous)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

And then add a policy that uses the new custom requirement...

```
public static void AddAuthorizationAndPolicies(this IServiceCollection services)
 {
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy("IsAnonymousUser",
                    policy => policy.AddRequirements( new AllowAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement()));
          
  });
}
```

**Note that this policy will DENY a user that IS authenticated - so is only useful in it's current state to specifically target anonymous users.**

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `PermissiveAuthorizationPolicy` like so and will let anyone through

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(ReverseProxyConfig.AuthPolicyName, policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new PermissiveAuthorizationPolicy())
        );
});


public class PermissiveAuthorizationPolicy : AuthorizationHandler<PermissiveAuthorizationPolicy>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissiveAuthorizationPolicy requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```